# Fourier series of $\arccos(\lambda\cos x$)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Please help with finding the (cosine) Fourier series of

$$f(x)=\arccos(\lambda\cos x),$$ where $\lambda$ is a real number, $|\lambda|<1$.

It is easy to find that $c_0=\pi/2$ and $c_{2n}=0$, but I do not see a way to integrate the expression for odd $n$. Any hint is welcome.

Comment: Do you mean $\arccos(\lambda \cos(x))$ or $\arccos(\lambda)\cos(x)$? The latter is much simpler than the former.

Comment: The former of course, what can be concluded already from the $c_0$ value. :)

Comment: fourier transform or fourier series?

Comment: I had in mind fourier series. If it really helps I can change the title.

Answer (score 0):

One idea: We know the arcus cosine series
$$
\frac{d}{du}\arccos  = -\frac1{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=-\sum\binom{2n}{n}\frac{u^{2n}}{4^n}
\\
\implies 
\arccos u=\frac\pi2-\sum\binom{2n}{n}\frac{u^{2n+1}}{4^n(2n+1)}
$$
Now insert $u=λ\cos x=\fracλ2(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$, which is permissible as $|u|<1$ is inside the series radius of convergence, apply the binomial theorem and sort the powers of $e^{ix}$.